# Avoid 'Memory Error" when dealing with large arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, out-of-memory

I'm facing sometimes `Memory Error`, sometimes it goes through fine and sometimes it pops up.. Specifically when trying to subtract large array by one. I tried many ways to do this subtraction, is there any way to avoid this? and is my other code parts will also sometime arise this error?

Here is my code:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        no_clus = int(request.POST.get('num_clusters', 10))
        if img.is_valid():

            paramFile =io.TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['pic'].file)
            portfolio1 = csv.DictReader(paramFile)

            users = []

            users = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in portfolio1]
            print(len(users))

            my_list = users
            vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
            dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

            lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
            dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
            dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
            dist1 = (1- np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T))
            # print(1-similarity)
            k = len(my_list)
         #   dist1 = (1- similarity)
            # dist1=similarity
            # dist1.astype(float)
            #print(dist1)
            # print(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[3:4], tfidf_matrix))
            # float dist = 1 - similarity;
            data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
            arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))
            # arr_3d= 1- arr_3d
            #print(arr_3d)

            no_cluster = number_cluster(len(my_list))
            print(no_cluster)
            for i in range(len(arr_3d)):
                # print (i+1910)
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='ward').fit(arr_3d[i])
                km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_cluster, linkage='average').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='complete').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = MeanShift()
                # km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_clus, init='k-means++')
                # km = MeanShift()
                #  km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
                # print km
                labels = km.labels_

            csvfile = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'\\'+ 'images\\export.csv'

            csv_input = pd.read_csv(csvfile, encoding='latin-1')
            csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
            csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
            csv_input.to_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv', index=False)
            clus_groups = list()
            for j in range(no_cluster):
                # print(" cluster no %i:%s" % (j, [my_list[i] for i, x in enumerate(labels) if x == j]))
                list_of_ints = ([my_list[i] for i, x in enumerate(labels) if x == j])
                clus_groups.append('  '.join(list_of_ints))
            vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
            dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

            lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
            dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
            dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
            dist1 = (1 - np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T))
           # similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
            k = len(my_list)
          #  dist1 = 1 - similarity

            data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
            arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))
            # arr_3d= 1- arr_3d

            #no_clus = 5
           # no_clus=get_name(request)
            for i in range(len(arr_3d)):
                # print (i+1910)
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='ward').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='average').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='complete').fit(arr_3d[i])
                km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_clus, init='k-means++')
                km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
                # print km
                labels2 = km.labels_
                # error = km.inertia_
                print(labels2)

            labels = labels.tolist()
            labels2 = labels2.tolist()
            # new=list()


            csv_input = pd.read_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv',encoding='latin-1')
            labels1 = csv_input['cluster_ID']
            new_list = []
            for k in labels1:
                new_list.append(labels2[k])  # lookup the value in list2 at the index given by list1

            print(new_list)
            print(len(new_list))
            csv_input = pd.read_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv',encoding='latin-1')
            csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
            csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
            csv_input['User_Map'] = new_list
            csv_input.to_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + 'output1.csv', index=False)
            #filename= settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv'
            send_file(request)
           # my_list = portfolio
            #save_file('output1.csv')
          #  csv(request)
          #  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('labels'))
            return render(request, 'new.html', {'labels': labels})
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'new.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

the `error` is when trying to do `dist1 = (1- np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T))` .. I also tried to create new array with all ones with the same size and then subtract.. How should I modify this to prevent this error? Note that the user interface that will run this code can be operated on any pc!

Comment: You shouldn't have to create an array with all 1's, you should just be able to do: `new_array = my_array - 1`

Comment: Well, I wanted 1- my_array, and That's what I'm doing originally

Comment: my bad, I just saw that. Why not just use arrays instead of casting them to matrices? I'm not sure about the internals but a copy of the data is probably happening in there. Just keep them as arrays and then use `np.dot(dtm_lsa, dtm_lsa.T)` ?

Comment: Do you think matrices taking more memory?

Comment: The problem is that it's occupationally happening, so can't test for sure

Comment: I think that once its created it shouldn't matter, but in the process of creating the matrix numpy might be doing a full copy. It starts as an np.arrray -> np.matrix -> np.array. Just keep it as array

Comment: I tried it but still having the error