# Memory Error when fitting the data using sklearn package

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, data-fitting

Following my question here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844596/avoid-memory-error-when-dealing-with-large-arrays`, I was able to deal with the `Memory Error` due to arrays operations by splitting them into several lines; thank to the guys responded. The problem now is it's throwing `Memory Error` when fitting the data using `Sklearn packages`; e.g when trying to do `.fit(arr_3d[i])` to `km` in the code below.

The array dimension is 3D, and I'm looping through it, so why I'm having this error? and how to fix it? note it doesn't happen all the time, sometimes it works fine with no error, not sure why either.

Whole code is:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        no_clus = int(request.POST.get('num_clusters', 10))

        if img.is_valid():

            paramFile =io.TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['File'].file)
            portfolio1 = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
            users = []
            users = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in portfolio1]


            my_list = users
            vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
            dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

            lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
            dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
            dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
            product= (np.dot(dtm_lsa, dtm_lsa.T))
            dist1 = (1 - product)
            k = len(my_list) ### length is 5362 
            data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
            arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))

            print(arr_3d) ### shown below
            print(len(arr_3d))
            no_cluster = number_cluster(request,len(my_list))
            print(no_cluster)
            for i in range(len(arr_3d)):
                #km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='ward')
                #km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
              #  km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_cluster, init='k-means++')
                km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_cluster, linkage='complete')
                km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
                #km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_cluster, linkage='average').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='complete').fit(arr_3d[i])
                # km = MeanShift()
                # km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_clus, init='k-means++')
                # km = MeanShift()
                #  km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
                # print km
                labels = km.labels_

            csvfile = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'\\'+ 'images\\export.csv'

            csv_input = pd.read_csv(csvfile, encoding='latin-1')
            csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
            csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
            csv_input.to_csv(settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ 'output.csv', index=False)
```

arr_3d is:

```
 [[[  0.00000000e+00   9.87752905e-01   1.00070800e+00 ...,   8.93937985e-01
     1.00352321e+00   1.00481892e+00]
  [  9.87752905e-01  -2.22044605e-16   1.00107768e+00 ...,   9.80156085e-01
     1.00047940e+00   1.00059883e+00]
  [  1.00070800e+00   1.00107768e+00  -6.66133815e-16 ...,   9.97548342e-01
     9.99890765e-01   1.00143594e+00]
  ..., 
  [  8.93937985e-01   9.80156085e-01   9.97548342e-01 ...,  -2.22044605e-16
     2.34431311e-01   9.87267801e-01]
  [  1.00352321e+00   1.00047940e+00   9.99890765e-01 ...,   2.34431311e-01
    -2.22044605e-16   1.00152421e+00]
  [  1.00481892e+00   1.00059883e+00   1.00143594e+00 ...,   9.87267801e-01
     1.00152421e+00   3.33066907e-16]]]
```

Comment: Sorry to persecute you with my comments :) It seems to be the same root cause: using too much memory in one iteration: you should set unused large data to "None" like dtm_lsa, product1, ... and maybe call garbage collector at that point before entering your loop.

Comment: I understand why the problem is happening, but not sure I understand your solution?? @jean-Francois Fabre

Comment: You've got huge useless data here: data2 = np.asarray(dist1) now that arr_3d has been created. Just set data2 = dist1 = None to garbage collect useless data. Sometimes in such cases it's better to create an aux. function because every temp variable is freed on function return without any extra effort.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Can you show me how to create this function please?